# Recreating a transformer using gyrators

Tags: transformer, spice, gyrator

I have a transformer that I would like to recreate using gyrators. What I know about it:

- two coils wrapped around the same core
- the resistance and inductance of each coil
- the coupling factor
- the parallel output resistance

I don't know the number of turns or the ratio of turns.

It seems I need to feed the output of one gyrator into another. Here is a circuit that I have tried but it fails dismally. For now I am keeping the inductance of the two coils the same.

The ptp of the input is 2 V with average of 0 V but the ptp of the output is less than 0.001 V with an average of 12.6 V, so clearly I am misunderstanding.

Is what I want to do even possible?

[image]

Comment: when you say "fails dismally", what does it do?

Comment: @danmcb Fails dismally because the output I described in my post is nothing like the output one would expect from a transformer.

Comment: Not asked, but a good approximation for the turns ratio in practical tightly wounded transformers is (N1/N2) = sqrt(L1/L2)

Comment: I get downvoted because I described a problem, described a circuit I have tried and the results it gives? What more is needed?

Comment: I guess someone wants to know what's the reasoning process behind the design you made. I have guessed the process in my answer, but I have not downvoted this question.

Comment: @user287001 You nailed the reasoning process in your answer, like you read my mind. I have to absorb what you wrote in your answer still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This screenshot from Wikipedia article of Gyrator tells what such item does:

[image]

The full article is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrator

Unfortunately our traditions have got distortions. One of them is that many of us have started to use term "gyrator" otherwise. In numerous circuit diagram explanations simulated inductors shown in the next image are called gyrators:

[image]

The image is presented in the same article as an practical application of the idea of the gyrator.

Note that the original gyrator is a 2-port, but the simulated inductor has only one port like an inductor.

I guess you have seen also this image in the same Wikipedia article:

[image]

But you found only the simulated inductor circuit when you searched a schematic of a practical gyrator. A web search for "gyrator" really gives numerous plausible looking articles where the common simulated inductor circuits are called gyrators. The shown applications in the search results may well work OK, only the name gyrator is used differently than it was originally defined.

But you obviously cascaded 2 simulated inductors without any actual thinking except "where I should connect the 2nd gyrator to? Oh, yes, naturally the output is the output of the opamp, so let's put the wire there!"

Unfortunately the result is pure nonsense. Restart by learning proper opamp realizations of gyrators. They are shown for ex here: [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee100/fa04/lab/lab10/EE100_Gyrator_Guide.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee100/fa04/lab/lab10/EE100_Gyrator_Guide.pdf)

Simulating the frequency dependent function of coupled inductors with opamp circuits is tricky. It must be based on the 2-port equations of a pair of coupled inductors. Gyrator is not by any means a must. It's enough that the circuit fulfills the 2-port equations:

[image]

The circuit drawing and equations above are taken from here: https://www.uni-ruse.bg/disciplines/TE/Lecture%20notes/Lectures%20notes%20Mutually%20coupled%20inductors.pdf

Not asked, but opamp circuits which simulate inductors do not accumulate energy to magnetic field, so they are not especially useful for ex. in switchmode power supplies.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm thinking a lack of magnetic field will stop me from doing what I want but I will simulate the circuit in the paper you linked to and see if I can get a step closer.

Answer (score 0):

Raj Senani et al. describes how a transformer can be realized with gyrators, which are in turn realized with operational transconductance amplifiers in their book "Gyrators, Inductors and Simulated Immitances—Realizations and Applications" on page 138. To understand the design, I recommend reading the first three chapters of the book.

[image: Transformer realized by operational transconductance amplifiers]